# Perfomance of the PAGE_WRITECOPY windows internal memory

Tags: performance, copy-on-write

I need to implement the undo-redo feature in an application, which reads a project file and makes  a sequence of separate transactions changing the project's content. The project can be hundreds MB large.

My idea is to implement the undo-redo on the basis of the copy-on-write (PAGE_WRITECOPY) memory mechanism. I assume that after the end of a transaction the application can access both changed and unchanged pages, compare them, identify the changed records, store original record states in the dedicated undo stack, free the created non-changed pages and restore the write-on-copy protection of the changed pages. I have two questions:

1. How and where I can found the addresses of the original (non-changed) pages.
2. The awaited performance of such an implementation?. The middle size of the project's records is cira 100 bytes. if a transaction changes 3000 records that may involve the change of 100 or more 4K physical pages. Is the write-on-copy memory performant enough to support the routineous change of the hundreds physical pages on each step?